# Download Data from SQL Database for use in iPhone App

Tags: objective-c, sql, ios4, nsdata, nsbundle

Can someone point me to a tutorial or some resource that will show me how I can download or use a sql database from a web server and use that content in an app. I want to control content in an app dynamically, such that each time the app is launched, it loads content from the database and uses that to populate the app.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to answer this question, but basically you should create a `REST` service (http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-rest/) in the language of your choice.

This will connect to the SQL Server database.

Then you create a `REST` client in your program ([consuming restful web service in iOS 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9359975/consuming-restful-web-service-in-ios-5)), and you can then interact with the database.

Answer (score 0):

[RestKit](http://Restkit.org) is an excellent library for build the iOS-side of a rest-driven system. Very actively supported, too. Has a nice tie-in for core data, too.